# Organizing view files in Node.js app

Tags: node.js

I finished [this walkthrough](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/) for creating a very basic Reddit clone using the MEAN stack. The app included a few different views, such as a view for all posts, a single post, the login form, and the register form, and all of these views were included in a single file: views/index.ejs.

Is putting all the views together like this common practice, or was it merely for brevity in the tutorial? I was hoping to be able to separate at least the login and register forms from the rest of the views in index.ejs for the sake of organization, but placing them in a login.ejs file in views causes a 404.

Login portion of views/index.ejs

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/login.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger row">
    <span>{{ error.message }}</span>
  </div>

  <form ng-submit="logIn()"style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Log In</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
  </form>
</script>
```

Login portion of routes/index.js

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    if(user){
      return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Login portion of controller

```
.state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: '/login.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
      onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
        if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
          $state.go('home');
        }
      }]
    })
```

I don't understand how the views fit together in this app. What is telling the app to find the login template in index.ejs, and how can I redirect the app to look in a different file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way they did this is a little strange, but it was most likely for the sake of brevity.

The reason why it's 404'ing is because of how the routes are set up. There's a single route to serve index.ejs, and the rest of the routing is handled client-side through Angular. In fact, the only reason they used ejs is because they wanted to send it using Express' [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) method most likely. (Although, since it's just HTML from what I saw, instead of actually using any EJS, they could likely just as easily used Express' [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) method, or prior to 4.8.0, [`res.send()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send) in conjunction with Node's builtin [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) to send the plain HTML file.

If you wanted to split out the views you'd have to set up server-side routes, but I guess they were dead set on a single-page app. More commonly, views that are rendered on the server-side are split out into individual files, with a main "layout", in which other views are included into.